# Disabling radio button based on user selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 sets of radio buttons with 4 options each. These 4 options are the same in both categories. I do not want to allow same selection to be possible in both categories.

For example - if option 1 is chosen is in the first category, the user can now only select from option 2/3/4 in the second category.

This question has been asked before, but nothing seems to be working for my case. Here is my code -

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  
  $("input[type=radio][value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

th:empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Most Supportive</th>
    <th>Reddit comment</th>
    <th>Most Offensive</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
    <td>Comment 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
    <td>Comment 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
    <td>Comment 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
    <td>Comment 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The way you have it is not how radio buttons are supposed to work, If I were you I would make the name comment1, comment2, comment3 ect.. for both the least and most, and set the value to indicate that it was the least/most of the particular comment. your backend would have to change a little too (where ever this is posting to.)  If you include it I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Giving them the same name for most and least, and different for comments would allow user to select multiple comments as offensive/supportive. Out of 4, I want them to select 1 offensive and 1 supportive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enable all radio buttons, then disable the one you would like to disable:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  console.log("here")
  $("input[type=radio]").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("input[type=radio][value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

th:empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Most Supportive</th>
    <th>Reddit comment</th>
    <th>Most Offensive</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
    <td>Comment 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
    <td>Comment 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
    <td>Comment 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
    <td>Comment 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: FYI: this allows you to select Most Supportive and Most Offensive for the same row - which, as I understand it, is exactly what OP didn't want.   Click supp for 1 -> off 1 disabled -> click off for 2 -> off 1 now enabled and can be selected

Comment: The answer posted allows only selection per row, which is what I wanted.