# How to make 2 sets of radio work independently?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I recently posted a query [Disabling radio button based on user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216541/disabling-radio-button-based-on-user-selection).

Though the answer given solves my original problem, I have run into a new issue.
I have two such tables where I want the user to select 1 option as most and 1 as least.

I want the radio buttons of both tables to work independently but in co-ordination with radio buttons in the same table. How can I do this? Here is the code -

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  // console.log("here")
  $("input[type=radio]").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("input[type=radio][value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

th:empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Most Supportive</th>
    <th>Reddit comment</th>
    <th>Most Offensive</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
    <td>Comment 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
    <td>Comment 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
    <td>Comment 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
    <td>Comment 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Most Supportive</th>
    <th>Reddit comment</th>
    <th>Most Offensive</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
    <td>Comment 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
    <td>Comment 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
    <td>Comment 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
    <td>Comment 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your issue get the `closest()` table and then base the selectors on finding content within that table. Note the use of `prop()` over `attr()` in the following example.

It's worth noting that this behaviour is a little odd. Firstly you don't let people change their selection as you disable the opposite checkbox. Also if you select any checkbox on another row, the checkbox becomes enabled again...?

*Update*

> Out of the given 4 options, I want the user to select 1 option for most offensive and 1 option for least offensive. They can't be the same option. So if someone selects option 1 on the right, I disable option 1 on the left. If they change their selection on the right, option 1 becomes available on left!

In this case you need to change your logic so that it only disables radios which have an opposing selection, not all of them. To do that loop through the rows of the table and evaluate them individually on change of each radio. Try this:

```js
$(":radio").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
    let $tr = $(this);
    $tr.find(':radio:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', $tr.find(':radio:checked').length == 1);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

th:empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Most Supportive</th>
    <th>Reddit comment</th>
    <th>Most Offensive</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
    <td>Comment 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
    <td>Comment 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
    <td>Comment 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most1" id="Most-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
    <td>Comment 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least1" id="Least-1d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Most Supportive</th>
    <th>Reddit comment</th>
    <th>Most Offensive</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
    <td>Comment 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2a" data-min-check="1" required value="a" data-col="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
    <td>Comment 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2b" data-min-check="1" required value="b" data-col="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
    <td>Comment 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2c" data-min-check="1" required value="c" data-col="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Most2" id="Most-2d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
    <td>Comment 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="Least2" id="Least-2d" data-min-check="1" required value="d" data-col="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks. Out of the given 4 options, I want the user to select 1 option for most offensive and 1 option for least offensive. They can't be the same option. So if someone selects option 1 on the right, I disable option 1 on the left. If they change their selection on the right, option 1 becomes available on left!

Comment: In that case you need to change your logic as when you select the second radio the previous ones get re-enabled again. I'll update the answer for you

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot. (I did not notice the bug for my use case, in the answer you posted earlier!)